# Scaffolding issue with fluid containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have some issues to fit my webpage as i would like using the bootstap scaffolding.

I am using the `fluid layout` in order to build a simple page, with the menu on the left and the content on its right.

I get 2 issues trying to do this:

1. There is no space between my both main containers.
2. Can we use the scaffolding inside our both containers (there is some code bellow) ? Or do we have to use the floats inside the `<div class="2">` and `<div class="10">` ?

Here is my code

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <script type="text/template" id="sidebar-template">
        ****** SIDE BAR ******
      </script>
      <div class="span2">
        <div id='sidebar-container'></div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/template" id="content-template">
        <p>****** CONTENT ******</p>
      </script>
      <div class="span10">
        <div id='content-container'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here are 3 screenshot of my first issue.

[Side bar](http://hpics.li/8003ae0)
[Content](http://hpics.li/6aa83af)
[Container](http://hpics.li/cf8bacf)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the expected left margin between the main containers when viewing your code (see fiddle below). Are you overriding it somewhere?
Also, you should add another `row-fluid` inside of your `span` to use scaffolding within an existing row.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qsd98/)
[Bootstrap example of nested scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) (view source)

**EDIT**
Your content is outside of the container divs. Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <div id='frontend-header-container'>
                <script type="text/template" id="frontend-header-template">
                    ****** SIDE BAR ******
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <div id='home-container'>
                <script type="text/template" id="home-template">
                    <p>****** CONTENT ******</p>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks this is the answer for my 2nd question. About the left margin, i don't think to override it, i just posted 3 sceenshot of what i get, i don't use additional CSS.

Comment: @Ludo can you post the exact HTML you're using? Those screenshots don't match the code in your question.

Comment: Ok i just posted it, i am using backbone so there are some additional divs.

Comment: @Ludo I'm unfamiliar with backbone, but my updated answer should work.